# How to create a white background to a jpg/png?

Tags: photos.app, photos, preview

I have a jpg of some logo, but its background is not completely white, more like light-greyish, whereas I would like it to be *perfectly* white.

I know how to select the background and also know how to turn that background to *transparent*, but not how turn that background to *white*.

If it can't be done with Preview, I also have iPhoto. I don't know how to do it there either.

NB: If the thing needs to be converted to a png in the process, that's fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know how to do that with Preview.app or iPhoto, but for this purpose you could use an online photo editor. First hit on google here is http://pixlr.com/editor/ - and it does the trick.

*(upload the image and you can make it white in several ways, e.g. by pressing B or G after you have set the main color to white, though there wil be more intelligent ways)*